# Size of dimensions for C++ vector of vectors

Tags: c++

As far as I understand, for a vector of vectors, the `vec.size()` gets the total size, while `vec[x].size()` gets the size of one dimension for each, say, row.

How to get the size of the other dimension?

Comment: Maybe just add them up?

Comment: Which "other dimensions" are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vector::size always returns the element count. So  vec.size() gets the number of vector rows. And  vec[x].size() will return elements in that row. It may be different for each x.  If you maintain a constant number, then total number of cells is  vec.size()*vec[0].size() (assuming not empty).

Comment: This helped me solve the question. I made a mistake thinking it gets the total size, while it gets the amount of vectors it holds. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

A vector of vectors has, in general, a jagged edge; there is no guarantee that the other dimension is constant.

Comment: But given it is equal among all, how to get it conveniently?

Comment: @Dualinity: If it's equal among all get the size and multiply it by the encasing size, no?

Comment: Just take the size of the zeroth element vec[0].size(); and hope that (i) the outer vector has at least one element and (ii) you don't have a jagged construct. Hope being very important here and not particularly future proof. I'd recommend you use a matrix class; say the one from boost.

Comment: I just realized now that the "rows" have no constant size, though.

Comment: Actually, and I'm in danger of this becoming a rant, using vector<vector< >> for a matrix is horrible on so many levels; memory being one of them.

Comment: @Dualinity Being 'equal among all' is domain knowledge. Encapsulate it in a class.

Comment: @Dualinity: if no constant size refer to my comment on your question, if nothing else smarter comes to mind. :)

Comment: What if based on the first element? I am not interested in the ith by jth item which could be not existant, I am just interested how many contain at least 1 item.

Comment: @Dualinity, Use `std::count_if` with `empty()`.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand, for a vector of vectors, the vec.size()

No, it gives the number of vectors inside that vector. That would correspond to the number of rows, if you see the vector as a kind of row-major 2D array.

So, if all the vectors inside the vector of vector have the same size, and assuming this size is equal to or greater than 1, then

```
auto dim1 = vec.size();
auto dim2 = vec[0].size();
```